# learning_curve not plotting more than 2 million records

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

I am trying plot sklearn `learning_curve` of 3 million training data where `LGBMClassifier` is the estimator. But when I plot the `learning_Curve` is shows only till 2 million records.

Please find my code below:

```
train_sizes, train_scores, validation_scores = learning_curve(
                                 estimator = lgb_estimator,
                                      X = train,
     y = target, train_sizes = np.linspace(0.1,1,5), cv = 3,
                scoring = 'roc_auc')

plt.style.use('seaborn')

plt.plot(train_sizes, train_scores_mean, label = 'Training error')
plt.plot(train_sizes, validation_scores_mean, label = 'Validation error')

plt.ylabel('MSE', fontsize = 14)
plt.xlabel('Training set size', fontsize = 14)
plt.title('Learning curves for a linear regression model', fontsize = 18, y = 1.03)
plt.legend()
plt.ylim(0.1,1)
```

Please till is this an expected behaviour or we can plot any number of records through sklearn `learning_curve`. Please let me know the code which will plot learning curve with any number of records

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your xlim

```
plt.xlim(0,3000000)
```